# Creating a table syntax errors in sql

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a SQL table for a school assignment. I'm required to name the constraints, and I am receiving a syntax error when creating my table

```
SELECT * FROM demo;

CREATE TABLE PRODUCT
(
    ProductID NUMBER,
    ProductDescription VARCHAR(200),
    CONSTRAINT ProductPK PRIMARY KEY (ProductID)
);

CREATE TABLE ITEM 
(
    ItemNum NUMBER
    CONSTRAINT Inull NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT ItemPK PRIMARY KEY(ItemNum),
    ItemDesc VARCHAR(200)
);
```

The syntax error is as follows:

> near "(": syntax error

It is likely something simple, but this is my first time writing SQL.

Comment: `... CONSTRAINT ItemPK PRIMARY KEY(ItemNum),`. Should either be a table constraint (comma before), or skip the (ItemNum) at the end.

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few errors ..  One, you are missing commas after `ItemNum NUMBER` and  `CONSTRAINT Inull NOT NULL`

Additionally there are other ways to define `NOT NULL`, you technically don't need to use `CONSTRAINT` in traditional SQL.

And depending on the flavor of SQL you are using .. I like to use `INT` or `INTEGER` instead of `NUMBER` -- It's basically the same as `NUMBER()` with a few exceptions, but if you are using **whole numbers** I would use `INT` or `INTEGER`

```
SELECT * FROM demo;

create TABLE PRODUCT
(
    ProductID INT,
    ProductDescription VARCHAR(200),
    CONSTRAINT ProductPK PRIMARY KEY (ProductID)
);
CREATE TABLE ITEM 
(
    ItemNum INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT ItemPK PRIMARY KEY(ItemNum),
    ItemDesc VARCHAR(200)
);
```

**UPDATE**

And as @Schwern suggests .. Your query can be further simplified, as there really is no need for `CONSTRAINTS` here ..  I would also recommend `Auto Incrementing` your IDs ..  Thus removing the need for `NOT NULL` on the ID.  This also negates the need to *supply* an ID with the `INSERT` query ..

```
SELECT * FROM demo;

create TABLE PRODUCT
(
    ProductID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ProductDescription VARCHAR(200)
);
CREATE TABLE ITEM 
(
    ItemNum INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ItemDesc VARCHAR(200)
);
```

Comment: @Justin One also doesn't need to put the primary key in its own constraint, and primary keys are already not null. `ProductID int primary key` and `ItemNum int primary key` are sufficient. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ed340122ffba353a2aa8c2d4327aa48d)